# Moq parent method being called in child class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have a base class with a protected method that's being called in a public method in the child class I want to test. I'm failing to find a way to moq the base protected method for easier testing in child class.

```
public class MyBaseClass
{
    protected virtual bool MyMethod(int number)
    {
        return number == 1;
    }   
}

public class MyChildClass : MyBaseClass
{
    public bool DoSomething(int number)
    {
        return MyMethod(number);
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class MyChildClassTests
{
    [Test]
    public void Expected_Returns_False_WhenPassed_1()
    {
        var myChildClass = new MyChildClass();

        // How do I mock MyMethod used in myBaseClass here?
        // var mock = new Mock<MyBaseClass>();
        // mock.Protected().Setup<bool>("MyMethod", ItExpr.IsAny<int>()).Returns(false);
        
        // The above mock is correct, but it's in a different instance object than myBaseClass

        var result = myChildClass.DoSomething();

        Assert.AreEqual(false, result);
    }
}
```

I can't change the classes to have a better architecture and I must do the best I can to implement unit test for `DoSomething()`, what I did so far is mock and prepare all the data that method uses, but since it's in another class I'd love my `MyChildClassTests` to not do all that and just limit to test `DoSomething()`.

I've read about partial mocking and a whole lot of other questions and answers and I can't get it to work right.

I appreciate any suggestions!

Edit: Forgot to put `public` in all the classes, in my real world case, they are public.

Comment: Since you have a virtual method you can create a FakeChildClass and override the MyMethod() . This will help you make the method protected and also do unit test on it.

Comment: Sorry but I don't follow. What do I gain when overriding MyMethod? How do I mock it? And the method I want to unit test is DoSomething(), how would I go about testing FakeChildClass with the overrided MyMethod()?

Comment: Why are you mocking this?   You are unit-testing MyChildClass.  It's a very simple class which does not need to be mocked for the unit tests you plan to do.

Mocking is more appropriate where something is relying on an abstraction that you don't want to have to spin up to do unit tests (e.g. you'd mock a data layer to test a business layer).

Honestly don't know what you're gaining by mocking here.

Comment: @PaulAlanTaylor the classes I posted are simplified examples, MyMethod in MyBaseClass in my project is pretty complex and calls to other APIs and have other dependencies that MyChildClass does not. That's why, when I'm building unit tests for MyChildClass, I don't want to provide mocks and set up all the required data that MyBaseClass needs or uses and I'd like to mock it and just care about MyChildClass. MyBaseClass already has its own unit test battery testing the behavior of MyMethod (and all the other methods in that class) and I don't want to repeat code and have it on MyChildClass again

Comment: Even if you're using a simplified example for the question, it might help if you clarify what you want to test, because it's not obvious. For example, somewhere in your example code you could put a line that does something, and then clarify - I want to make sure that this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your replies, gathering all I was able to get the actual answer to my use case:

Without changing `MyBaseClass` and `MyChildClass`:

```
public class MyBaseClass
{
    protected virtual bool MyMethod(int number)
    {
        return number == 1;
    }   
}

public class MyChildClass : MyBaseClass
{
    public bool DoSomething(int number)
    {
        return MyMethod(number);
    }
}
```

I was able to mock the protected method and save me a LOT of work and duplicate code (that was in MyBaseClassTests already)

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyChildClassTests
{
    [Test]
    public void Expected_Returns_False_WhenPassed_1()
    {
        var expected = false;
        var myChildClass = new Mock<MyChildClass> {CallBase = true};
        myChildClass.Protected().Setup<bool>("MyMethod", 1).Returns(expected);
        
        var result = myChildClass.Object.DoSomething(1);

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, result);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Expected_Returns_True_WhenPassed_1()
    {
        var expected = true;
        var myChildClass = new Mock<MyChildClass> {CallBase = true};
        myChildClass.Protected().Setup<bool>("MyMethod", 1).Returns(expected);
        
        var result = myChildClass.Object.DoSomething(1);

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, result);
    }
}
```

Thanks everyone for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyChildClassTests
{
    [Test]
    public void Expected_Returns_False_WhenPassed_1()
    {
        var myChildClass = new FakeChildClass();
        
        var result = myChildClass.DoSomething(1);

        Assert.AreEqual(false, result);
    }
}

public class FakeChildClass: MyChildClass
{
    protected override bool MyMethod(int number)
    {
        return number == 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Smitha Kalluz for taking the time to help me! Sadly I still don't see the benefit on what you are doing.

MyMethod in MyBaseClass returns true under some circumstances and false under others (it even throws an exception if something goes wrong). It's not just about comparing a number, that's just an example.
The idea is to mock the method in one test and force it to return false, then in another test, mock it to return true, and in another mock it to throw an exception.

Comment: A child class object is used to call the method. Protected is used to protect the members from being accessed outside of class.  So by declaring any constructor as protected, we can call it from a subclass. We cannot call a protected method.
 Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

First of all, ensure your classes are public.

Moq will complain about not being able to proxy into them if they're not.

```
public class MyBaseClass
{
    public virtual bool MyMethod(int number)
    {
        return number == 1;
    }   
}

public class MyChildClass : MyBaseClass
{
    public bool DoSomething(int number)
    {
        return MyMethod(number);
    }
}
```

Next, make your base class method public.   You won't be able to set it up unless you do.

After that, create a mock of the **child** object and mock the parent method.

```
var mockChild = new Mock<MyChildClass>(){CallBase = true};
            mockChild.Setup(x => x.MyMethod(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(false);
```

Pull your result....   **result** will return false even though the actual implementation would have returned true with 1 as a parameter.

```
var result = mockChild.Object.DoSomething(1);
```

When calling the DoSomething method, you'll actually enter the real implementation of that (put a breakpoint on if you don't believe me!) - but the mocked version of MyMethod will kick in.